# I cannot initialize a NSInputStream

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstream, nsinputstream

Please help me, im going insane.
I need to create an `NSInputStream` so i can read a live preview from a camera over wifi.
liveViewStream is an `NSInputStream`-Instance-Variable that is declared in my implementation like so:

```
@implementation MKSonyCamHandler{
    NSInputStream *liveViewStream;
}
```

`liveViewURL` is a valid URL that i can open in my browser when i connect to the camera's network (although i dont think that this makes any difference). I have checked that it exists, is not nil and holds the value that i expect.
But when i do this:

```
liveViewStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithURL:liveViewURL];
DLog(@"%@", liveViewStream);
```

The DLog after the alloc-init commands will log "(null)" every time, and ill be damned if i know why. Has anybody ever encountered this? Am i missing something glaringly obvious here?
Its my first time working with `NSStreams`, is there a common pitfall that might be the reason?
The docs clearly state that -initWithURL:

```
Creates and returns an initialized NSInputStream object that reads data from
the file at a given URL.
```

Any ideas? Im starting to feel really stupid here.

EDIT: i am using ARC.

Comment: Are you certain that the URL is not nil, is a correct URL, is accessible and is delivering a stream of data?

Comment: @Jasarien - like i said, i can open it in my browser. I can log it. The debugger shows the correct value. I wouldnt know what else to check...

Comment: What opens in the browser when you access the URL?

Comment: @Jasarien - it shows a black page that echoes the url i entered. Also, the "loading-spinner" in Firefox wont stop spinning. looks like a stream to me.

Comment: @Jasarien - wireshark confirms that data is being delivered, too

Comment: @Jasarien - the problem is that its not a video stream, but some data that i need to convert into JPEGs after i receive them. I dont think firefox (or any other browser) could just display the stream without interpreting the header of the packages.

Comment: that's true, I was just trying to ascertain if there was data coming from the stream, but you've proven that there is, so I don't know what could be causing the issues here.

Comment: You could try downloading the data into a NSData, then use:   [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:TheData];

should be more reliable this way.

Comment: @leparlon - thanks for the suggestion, but it is a potentially infinite stream. Or can i just start downloading it into NSData and then sort of stream it from the unfinished data object? That sounds kinda weird to me. Ill try it on monday, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone, i found it.

The thing is, my question already had all the clues i would have needed, because, like i wrote, NSStream`s -initWithURL: will

```
Create and return an initialized NSInputStream object that reads data from
the file at a given URL.
```

What I didn't see is that this is only true for local sources. If you want a remote host, (i had a wireless network connection) you need to use something else, because, and i quote the docs again here:

```
The NSStream class does not support connecting to a remote host on iOS.
```

Well, for what its worth, you need to create a `CFReadStreamRef` and a `CFWriteStreamRef`, and then use the magic function `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` to connect them to your host. After that, you can cast them to `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` respectively, and they will work as intended. Heres a code example from the docs:

```
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;

    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], 80, &readStream, &writeStream);



    NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;

    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];

    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];

    [outputStream open];
```

Hope this helps someone at some point.

@leparlon:

Im upvoting your answer, since you were definitly on the right track, suggesting the use of initWithData.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ARC, that might fix it:

EDIT:
Downloading it into a NSData first might fix it

```
NSInputStream *tempStream;
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"Your Url"]; 
tempStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:tempData]; 
liveViewStream = tempStream; 
DLog(@"%@", liveViewStream);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but it didnt work. Now both tempStream and liveViewStream are (null).

Comment: Check my new answer if you're still interested ;)